# Why use a proxy when I could use CURLOPT_INTERFACE?

Tags: php, curl

For work I have to deal with a lot of cURL and a question I came up with today is what exactly is the difference between `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` and using a proxy via cURL?
Could I not potentially just change the IP address through `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` and then have the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` just be the assigned IP address through `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`?

Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_INTERFACE will only work if you specify an IP that is tied to the machine (/etc/network/interface on Linux). CURLOPT_PROXY is used to rout traffic through your interface and out to the remote server where the proxy is.If you try to set CURLOPT_INTERFACE to a remote IP that is not on your machine curl will fail as it does not exist on your machine and can't be found.

Example:
If on your server you have 2 IP's: 1.1.1.1   2.2.2.2
You have a proxy with the ip 9.9.9.9 on a remote machine
Php curl can be configured to go out on the interface 2.2.2.2 and connect through the proxy 9.9.9.9. This will allow you to run all your webpages on 1.1.1.1 and ban all outbound traffic on 1.1.1.1 while still allowing your app the ability to get out through 2.2.2.2.

If you do not specify, curl will use the default (In most cases the first one specified in /etc/network/interface)